# Can't save my email address.

Tags: bug

I visited [this page](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/8674) and changed the email address listed under "Send notification emails to". However, the changes don't appear to stick. As soon as the page is reloaded, the old value appears in the box.

I opened up Chrome's inspector and verified that the new value was being sent in the POST request to `/accounts/verified-email-set`. The JSON response is simply:

```
{"success":true,"message":"you will no longer receive unread inbox messages via email"}
```

Comment: Nathan what email do you expect to see? I am seeing @qms (redacted for privacy).

Comment: @Steve I'm seeing admin@qms even after changing it to nathan@qms.

Comment: I don't know what is causing this but they recently changed the login system. What are you using to login stackoverflow or a social media linked account?

Comment: @Steve actually I'm using an OpenID.

Comment: Because you are using openid it may be using that email. though I would expect a bit more indication of that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are still having a problem with this, I suggest you post a question on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive).  No one here, including us moderators, is responsible for anything technical.  We didn't design the site, we don't have any more access to the servers than you do, etc.  I believe the server side code is public (and mostly ruby), but I've never bothered to look.

Occasionally SE staff do peruse our meta, but I have no idea how regularly.   However, if you post on SE.meta and use the `bug` tag, someone responsible will notice fairly quickly and either acknowledge the bug, ask you for more information, or explain what you are doing wrong.